# SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model - "'The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, sharepoint-2010

I attempting to write a proxy for the SharePoint 2010 web services to get around NTLM authentication for another set of services we are writing in Ruby. I have developed it, and when I debug it in the asp.net server in visual studio, I am able to get and parse the data fine. However, when I deploy it to our IIS server, I get the following error:

```
"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"
```

I am using the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model to do the connection to a self-signed Sharepoint site I have full control access to. Again, this works perfectly fine when I debug it, but on IIS it throws that error with the following Stacktrace:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute() at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest() at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() at
SharepointProxy.SharepointProxy.GetListData(String listName) in
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio
2010\Projects\SharepointWSProxy\SharepointProxy\SharepointProxy.svc.cs:line 56 at
SharepointProxy.SharepointProxy.GetEmployees() in \\psf\home\documents\visual studio
2010\Projects\SharepointWSProxy\SharepointProxy\SharepointProxy.svc.cs:line 19 at
SyncInvokeGetEmployees(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[]
inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
rpc) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
isOperationContextSet)
```

Here's the relevant bit of code. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://url.to.subsite");
List destList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery();
qry.ViewXml = "<Valid Query>";
ListItemCollection items = destList.GetItems(qry);
context.Load(items);
context.Load(destList);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Line 56 above is where it references the items variable. It's the line right under this.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm utterly stumped as to why it works in debug but not on IIS.

Comment: That error is almost always a problem with certificates.  Where do you set the certificate in your call?